# Messed up my hybrid graphics configuration

Tags: graphics

I was trying to make the switch possible between my Intel and Radeon AMD graphic card following this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450, but apparently the installation of the packages messed up my default configuration (yeah, my graphic cards weren't in the list of "supported"...but I wanted to check anyways!), which caused compiz to crash and I don't know how to restore the default configuration so compiz will work again.

I was at Step 1, in the part when it says:

> and configure the Xserver (xorg.conf file) for the first time:
>
> sudo aticonfig --initial -f

After that, I rebooted and everything crashed. Is there a way to go back? Thanks in advance.

**Technical specifications**

I own an HP Envy 15-3040NR, which has:

- Processor: i7-2670QM.
- Graphic cards: **AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series and a 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller**. I
- I'm running on Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manually installing fglrx ruins your OS.  tsk tsk.  May as well wipe and reinstall.  You can try deleting xorg.conf, purging all fglrx, and undoing all edits.

Comment: What I finally did was to re-install Ubuntu :-(.